# Angular array values connected to ng-model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm using two `<select>` tags to push values to an array in the `$scope`. For some reason this array then becomes connected to the `select` elements and when they are changed it changes the array elements.

I have made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/pjdyKY?editors=101) to demonstrate this behaviour.

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label positive">
          Select Parameter
        </div>
        <select ng-model="data.param">
          <option ng-repeat="param in params track by $index" value="{{param}}">{{param}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label positive">
          {{data.param || 'SELECT'}}
        </div>
        <select ng-model="data.childParam">
          <option ng-repeat="child in children[data.param] track by $index" value="{{child}}">{{child}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addParam(data)"> SAVE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="savedParm in activeExercise.Params track by $index" class="list-group-item"><strong>{{savedParm.param}}</strong> : {{savedParm.childParam}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{activeExercise.Params}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addParam = function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if (!$scope.activeExercise.Params) {
        $scope.activeExercise.Params = [];
    }

    if ($scope.activeExercise) {

        $scope.activeExercise.Params.push(data);

    } else if ($scope.editExercise.Params) {

        $scope.editExercise.Params.push(data);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.activeExercise));

}
```

Comment: use bind instead of model

Comment: `ng-bind` on the select elements? doesn't to work.

Comment: you add to array reference to object, so when you change select, change property this object, but not obect reference, so, for solving try copy object fields like: `var ndata = {param:data.param, childParam:data.childParam}` and then push to array `ndata` object instead `data`

Comment: @Grundy works perfectly... thanks...feel free to write an answer and I will mark it as correct. Or I will add it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add to array reference to object, so when you change value in select, you change property existing object, but not object reference, so all reference point to object with updated field.
for solving you can copy object fields to new object, like:

```
var ndata = {param:data.param, childParam:data.childParam}
```

and then push to array `ndata` object instead `data`